# Почему не правильно работает сумма на определенном значении?

Tags: c++

Пишу класс Time. На вход подается время в секундах и затем получается итоговое время dd:hh:mm:ss. Перезагрузил оператор + для суммы двух времен. По итогу на значение 200 000 секунд не правильно работает (вместо 4 дней выводит 0), на остальных, которые проверял, выводит правильно. В чем ошибка?

Перегрузка:

```
TimeSpan operator+(const TimeSpan &t1, const TimeSpan &t2) {
    TimeSpan sumTime;

    sumTime.days = t1.days + t2.days;
    //std::cout << t1.days << " " << t2.days << " " << sumTime.days << std::endl;
    if(t1.hours + t2.hours > 24) {
        sumTime.days++;
        std::cout << sumTime.days << std::endl;
        sumTime.hours = t1.hours + t2.hours - 24;
    } else 
        sumTime = t1.hours + t2.hours;
    if (t1.minutes + t2.minutes > 60) {
        sumTime.hours++;
        sumTime.minutes = t1.minutes + t2.minutes - 60;
    } else
        sumTime.minutes = t1.minutes + t2.minutes;
    if (t1.seconds + t2.seconds > 60) {
        sumTime.minutes++;
        sumTime.minutes  = t1.seconds + t2.seconds - 60;
    } else 
        sumTime.seconds = t1.seconds + t2.seconds;

    return sumTime;
}
```

main.cpp

```
lab1::TimeSpan Time = TimeSpan(200000);
lab1::TimeSpan Time2 = TimeSpan(200000);
lab1::TimeSpan Res;
Res = Time + Time2;
int days = Res.getDays();
std::cout << days << std::endl;  //trash days = 0
```

Comment: Никогда не видел на часах 24:00, максимум 23:59:59 и потом уже 00::00:00 и с секундами то же самое.

Comment: Тут немного другое, здесь не время как на часах, а в формате dd:hh:mm:ss

Comment: ладно, Вам виднее. По коду у Вас есть много секунд и только ОДИН раз происходит инкремент минут, а часы и дни не меняются.

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема в том, что Вы начинаете суммировать с дней, хотя по логике должны начинать с секунд. Ещё есть ошибка в блоке, где суммируются секунды, а именно строку

```
sumTime.minutes  = t1.seconds + t2.seconds - 60;`
```

нужно заменить на

```
sumTime.seconds  = t1.seconds + t2.seconds - 60;
```

И вообще, Вас же есть конструктор, который умеет переводить время из секунд в нужный формат. Используйте его:

```
TimeSpan operator+(const TimeSpan &t1, const TimeSpan &t2)
{
    unsigned long long t1TotalSecs = t1.days * 24 * 3600 + t1.hours * 3600 + t1.minutes * 60 + t1.seconds;
    unsigned long long t2TotalSecs = t2.days * 24 * 3600 + t2.hours * 3600 + t2.minutes * 60 + t2.seconds;

    return TimeSpan(t1TotalSecs + t2TotalSecs);
}
```

Если реализовать закрытый метод `asSeconds`, то Ваш оператор вообще превратится в однострочник:

```
TimeSpan operator+(const TimeSpan &t1, const TimeSpan &t2)
{
    return TimeSpan(t1.asSeconds() + t2.asSeconds());
}
```